# Expo React Native Drawer Navigator Logout functionality

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

StackOverflow I am very new to react native since I implement drawer navigation now I want to include a logout button at the end of the drawer but I don't find how to do that any good practice and ideas about how to achieve this kind of functionality. this is my code for drawer I find it from hours of google and it works fine but it has functions of screens I don't find any option of how to make a logout link in this code if this code is not correct then suggest any other good snippet thanks in advance

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

// _signOutAsync = async () => {
//   await AsyncStorage.clear();
//   this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
// };
const HomeScreen = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home Screen!</Text>
  </View>
);


const ProfileScreen = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Profile Screen!</Text>
  </View>
);


const SettingsScreen = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Settings Screen!</Text>
  </View>
);

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen, 
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home Screen', 
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={20} />
      )
    })
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen, 
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Profile Screen', 
      drawerLabel: 'Profile',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={20} />
      )
    })
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen, 
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-settings" size={20} />
      )
    })
  },
 
});


const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  DrawerNavigator: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator, 
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const { state } = navigation;

      if(state.isDrawerOpen) {
        return {
          headerLeft: ({titleStyle}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}}>
              <Ionicons name="ios-close" style={styles.menuClose} size={36} color={titleStyle} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
         
        }
      }
      else {
        return {
          headerLeft: ({titleStyle}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}}>
              <Ionicons name="ios-menu" style={styles.menuOpen} size={32} color={titleStyle} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          
          ),
          
        }
        
      }
      
    }
  }
})

export default  createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

Comment: you can create a logout component, where you can just write code to navigate to login screen or your initial screen by clearing your auth token from async storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one content component to render inside your Drawer Navigator, making it easier to modify.
I will explain with your example (I am assuming that it is your App.js file):

```
//import CustomDrawer from '...'
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen, 
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home Screen', 
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={20} />
      )
    })
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen, 
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Profile Screen', 
      drawerLabel: 'Profile',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={20} />
      )
    })
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen, 
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-settings" size={20} />
      )
    })
  }, 
 //Here you will add one more pair of curly brackets to add more configs.
}, {
   initialRouteName: 'Home',
   contentComponent: CustomDrawer //This is the option that will allow you to add the button
});
```

You will create one entire component to modify like you want and then render inside the Drawer Navigator. Remember, I am using CustomDrawer name, you will import this component inside your App.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { DrawerNavigatorItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

const CustomDrawer = ({ ...props }) => {
    return (
        <>
        <View>
           <DrawerNavigatorItems
              {...props}
              itemsContainerStyle={{}}
              itemStyle={{}}
                 />
        </View>
        <View
            style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                position: 'relative',
                marginBottom: 20,
            }}
        >
            <Button
                title={'Log out'}
                buttonStyle={{ width: 200, borderRadius: 20 }}
                onPress={}
            />
        </View>
        </>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default CustomDrawer;
```

Here I am rendering only the CustomDrawer props, that is the itens that you create in your App.js and rendering it (specifically it is the ...props that I am passing in DrawerNavigationItems, so you can customize it like you want, like one normal screen, place buttons, create views and apply styles to it.

You can also instead of creating one new screen to render inside your Drawer Navigator code it inside your App.js, but personally I feel it much messed up

You can learn more with [this](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/customizing-react-navigation-drawer-cf60c01a296a) tutorial